# Alternative way to use as a Popup window on mobile website?

Tags: mobile-web

What would be the most alternative way to display information one clicks on an action and display information on mobile device without opening on different page?

Comment: Hi there. I think a more specific question with more details on what you're trying to achieve would allow us to help you more. :)

Comment: Hi! for example our website, non-profit organization, have a pictures and buttons that it urges visitor to click on and reveal more information behind it with popups. We are converting our current website to mobile friendly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! So you are developing a website for mobile. Are you trying not to use JavaScript, or are you just thinking there's a more user-friendly way to display information instead of pop-up windows on Phones?

Comment: I'm just thinking there might be a more user-friendly way to display information.

Answer (score 1):

One possible strategy is to try and apply more progressive disclosure patterns that allow you to show and hide information based on user actions. Some examples include:

- **tooltips**: but instead of showing it on a popup you would simply implement a collapse/expand accordion style of display area underneath or near the trigger. This is usually for small and concise chunks of text.
- **twisties** or show/hide: again this is designed to hide information but allow users to discover or reveal additional content if they want to. This is usually used for larger chunks of information.
- **notifications or messaging**: depending on the design/interaction guide for the component or development framework you are using, these can appear at the top of the page and be persistent, timed or dismiss-able.